# Not IN ou Not EXISTS qual usar?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Já vi alguns respostas aqui com o uso *Not In* e algumas com o uso do *Not Exists* para responder uma mesma pergunta.

*Eu não sei a diferença entre ambas e gostaria de saber sobre:*

- ***Qual dos dois é melhor quando se considera o desempenho?***
- ***Em quais ocasiões devo usar um e outro?***

*Se possível de exemplos com Query!*

Comment: Isso gerou um debate aqui na empresa ontem mesmo rs, o DBA comentando sobre o uso do `not in` e do `not exist` em um script que criamos

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio eu geralmente uso o not in, mais não sei qual dois é mais eficiente.

Comment: Eu uso o `not in` também. Não sei responder se tem melhor desempenho ou não.

Comment: Eu uso NOT EXISTS. Esta [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11074428/2556111) no SOen explica bem o que pode ser diferente no uso de cada uma delas.

Comment: Aqui tens uma outra razão para considerar evitar o uso do NOT IN (ou do IN): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722220/sql-in-clause-1000-item-limit

Comment: Obrigado pessoal.

Comment: [esse artigo no manual do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html) (em inglês) descreve algumas condições em que é possível otimizar consultas com *subqueries* usando `EXISTS`

Comment: @Sanção Obrigado.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Isso vai depender da situação.  O not in é recomendado quando você já tem os valores e passa como parametro, por exemplo:

```
select * from tbl where status_id not in (1,3,7)
```

Agora se você for fazer um subselect recomendo usar o not exists, pois no primeiro resultado que ele encontrar ele já irá validar e passar para o próximo registro.

```
select * from user u where not exists (select 1 from player p where p.user_id = u.id limit 1)
```

Como eu não preciso dos campos da tabela player o retorno 1 fica mais rapido do que *. O limite 1 (muda a forma de escrever de acordo com o banco de dados) vai fazer com que ao encontrar 1 registro já seja o suficiente para dizer que existe. Update: em algumas situações o limit 1 pode deixar mais rápido de acordo com esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10688065/2100693).

Espero que tenha ficado claro.

Desempenho: como o Paulo citou na resposta abaixo, o not exists permite a utilização de índice, o que em tabelas com muitos registros poderá melhorar em muito o desempenho em relação ao not in.

Comment: Muito boa a resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado! :)

Comment: Ótimo exemplo!!

Answer (score 15):

Complementando a resposta acima. O objetivo agora é encontrar todos os empregados que não são gestores. Vamos ver como podemos conseguir isso usando o `NOT IN` e `NOT EXISTS`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## NOT IN

```
SQL> select count(*) from emp_master where emp_nbr not in ( select mgr_nbr from emp_master );
COUNT(*)
———-
0
```

## **NOT EXISTS**

```
SQL> select count(*) from emp_master T1 where not exists ( select 1 from emp_master T2 where t2.mgr_nbr = t1.emp_nbr );

COUNT(*)
———-
9
```

Agora, existem 9 pessoas que não são gestores. Assim, você pode ver claramente a diferença que valores `NULL` fazem desde que `NULL! = NULL` no SQL, a cláusula `NOT IN` não retorna nenhum `registro` de volta.

## **Implicações de desempenho:**

Ao usar `NOT IN`, a consulta executa varreduras aninhados de tabela, enquanto que para `NOT EXISTS`, a consulta pode utilizar um índice dentro da sub-consulta.

Answer (score 7):

`EXISTS` é mais performático do que o `IN`, porém não vem a ser uma boa pratica, depende da sua necessidade....

O `in` "cria" uma estrutura de or's na sua condição sql, exp:

```
select * from tabela1
where idtabela in (select idtabela from tabela2 where condicao = 2)
```

Digamos que existam 5 condições = 2 de idtabela nessa tabela2 , o bd interpretaria o `in` como:

```
select * from tabela1 t
inner join tabela2 t2 on t2.idtabela = t.idtabela
where idtabela = 1 or idtabela = 2 or idtabela = 3 or idtabela = 4 or idtabela = 5
```

Agora ao usar o `exists` o bd "força" um relacionamento entre as duas tabelas
Ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
select * from tabela1 t
inner join tabela2 t2 on t2.idtabela = t.idtabela
where condicao = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

A resposta depende primeiro de qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados (sgbd) pois as implementações internas podem não ser as mesmas para NOT IN e NOT EXISTS.

No caso do SQL Server recentemente publiquei o artigo “[Qual é mais rápido: NOT IN ou NOT EXISTS?](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2020/05/02/not-in-x-not-exists/)” em que é tratada a questão de “*como saber quais elementos estão no conjunto A mas não estão no conjunto B*”. Além de NOT IN e NOT EXISTS são tratadas de outras opções como EXCEPT, LEFT OUTER JOIN e OUTER APPLY.

Em primeiro lugar, sempre é recomendado [analisar o plano de execução](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/11/21/o-plano-perfeito/). E é preciso ter em mente que o plano de execução gerado varia de acordo com vários fatores, inclusive com as características dos dados.

Em minha opinião não há como definir a priori qual método é o mais rápido.

Ao analisar outros artigos sobre o assunto percebe-se que em alguns foram utilizados casos em que a situação é otimizada para se obter determinada conclusão. Por exemplo, no artigo “[Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)”, de Aaron Bertrand, ele afirma logo no início do artigo que “*Instead of NOT IN, use a correlated NOT EXISTS for this query pattern. Always*”. Ou seja, segundo ele NOT EXISTS sempre é mais rápido. Entretanto, ele cita “*for this query pattern*“. Que padrão de consulta? Consulta direta entre somente duas tabelas e que possuam índices que permitam a junção direta entre as tabelas. Ora, aí é *mamão com açúcar*, *né*?

Já no artigo “[Consider using [NOT] EXISTS instead of [NOT] IN with a subquery](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/consider-using-not-exists-instead-not-subquery)”, de Phil Streiff, consta que “*It used to be that the EXISTS logical operator was faster than IN, when comparing data sets using a subquery*. (…) *However, the query optimizer now treats EXISTS and IN the same way, whenever it can, so you’re unlikely to see any significant performance differences*”.