# Select para Listar dados de outra tabela

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tenho um sistema do qual cadastra os dados pessoais `enc_dados_pessoais` e uma outra tabela que armazena dados complementares `enc_dados_complementares`.

Na tabela dados pessoais o usuário cadastra apenas as informações básicas e ao clicar em *avançar*, vai para os dados complementares. Estou precisando listar apenas os usuários que nao finalizaram os dados complementares.

A *chave primária* da tabela `enc_dados_pessoais` é `IdUsuarios` e a *chave estrangeira* da tabela `enc_dados_complementares` é `IdUsuarios`. Então fiz dessa forma:

```
SELECT * FROM enc_dados_principais princ LEFT JOIN enc_dados_complementares
comp ON princ.IdUsuarios <> comp.IdUsuarios;
```

Mas não está retornando quem não preencheu, somente quem preencheu os dados complementares.

Já tentei usar `INNER JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` e `JOIN`, mas também não funcionou.

Comment: você pode usar o not exists ou o not in. Dê uma olhada aqui. 
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62925/not-in-ou-not-exists-qual-usar

Comment: Obrigado Marconi. Usei o not in e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Por nada @Jose.Marcos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baseado no [comentário do colega Marconi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69279/select-para-listar-dados-de-outra-tabela/69287#comment141672_69279), resolvi o problema usando o `NOT IN`:

```
select * from enc_dados_principais where IdUsuarios not in 
(SELECT IdUsuarios FROM enc_dados_complementares);
```

Comment: Quando for possível, marque a resposta como aceita clicando sobre a marca ✔ abaixo da pontuação. =)

Comment: Olá qmechanik, tentei fazer isso, mas diz que "Você pode aceitar sua própria resposta em 2 dias" ... porém marquei o comentário do Marconi como útil.