# Como fazer um NOT IN SQL?

Tags: sql

Quero obter todos os pilotos que nunca realizaram voos na rota 12345, ja experimentei com NOT IN e assim:

```
SELECT pl.id
FROM Piloto pl,
 Voo v, Rota r           
WHERE  pl.id = v.id_comandante                  
AND pl.id = v.id_copiloto                       
AND v.cod_rota = r.cod_rota                 
AND r.cod_rota <> 12345
```

O SQL não retorna nada. O que estou a fazer mal?

Estas sao as tabelas:

```
Aviao (matricula, nome, data_aquisicao, TipoAviao.cod_tipo) 

Piloto (Tripulante.id, n_aterragens, n_descolagens, n_horas_voo, tipo) 

Habilitado (Piloto.id, TipoAviao.cod_tipo, n_licenca, data_licenca) 

Rota (cod_rota, Aeroporto.cod_aeroporto_ini, Aeroporto.cod_aeroporto_fim) 

Voo (n_voo, data_partida, data_chegada, Rota.cod_rota,

Piloto.id_comandante, Piloto.id_copiloto, Aviao.matricula)
```

Comment: Veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62925/not-in-ou-not-exists-qual-usar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Esteves, use a clausula IN com subquery com muita cautela, pois ele é muito caro seu processamento.

Entenda que, para cada registro de cada tabela do relacionamento do SQL, ele irá executa uma vez a subquery.

Então, se vc tem 10 pilotos e possui 50 rotas registradas, numa consulta dela vc irá executar 500x sua subquery.

Para este cenário, o ideal é usar LEFT JOIN, será mais performático e ideal.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pl.id
  FROM Piloto P
  LEFT JOIN Voo V ON V.ID_Comandante =  Pl.Id OR V.Id_CoPiloto = Pl.Id
  LEFT JOIN Rota R ON R.Cod_Rota = V.Cod_Rota AND R.Cod_Rota = 12345
 WHERE R.Cod_Rota IS NULL
```

Assim irá retornar todos os IDs de pilotos que nunca voaram pela rota 12345.

Answer (score 8):

Imagino que o problema é que o id não pode ser ao mesmo tempo do comandante e do co-piloto, então esta condição em particular é se o ID for de um OU de outro:

```
SELECT pl.id FROM Piloto pl, Voo v, Rota r
WHERE ( pl.id = v.id_comandante OR pl.id = v.id_copiloto )
   AND v.cod_rota = r.cod_rota
   AND r.cod_rota <> 12345
```

A sua original pedia para retornar quando o id fosse igual a um e a outro, condição impossível.

Quanto a excluir a 12345, provavelmente é o caso de subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM Piloto
WHERE id NOT IN (
   SELECT pl.id FROM Piloto pl, Voo v, Rota r
   WHERE pl.id = v.id_comandante OR pl.id = v.id_copiloto
   AND v.cod_rota = r.cod_rota
   AND r.cod_rota = 12345
)
```

O que fizemos aqui é transferir sua lógica para localizar os `id`s dos pilotos que fizeram a 12345, e retornar na query externa os que não estão nesse rol.

De qualquer forma, o caminho mais adequado é usar `JOIN` para unir as tabelas. Aqui tem uma explicação sobre o assunto:
[Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa desmembrar as consultas para chegar ao resultado ideal

Primeiro buscar Todos os pilotos que nunca usaram a rota X
Ex.:

```
SELECT pl.id
FROM Piloto pl
WHERE  pl.id NOT IN (
    SELECT pl2.id
    FROM Piloto pl2, Voo v, Rota r           
    WHERE  pl2.id = v.id_comandante                  
        AND pl2.id = v.id_copiloto                       
        AND v.cod_rota = r.cod_rota                 
        AND r.cod_rota = 12345  
) z
```

A partir daí você adiciona outras informações.