# SELECT em uma RELAÇÃO com AUTO-RELACIONAMENTO(Verificando Occorrências)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com dificuldade em fazer uma consulta.
A situação é a seguinte, preciso que o banco retorne todos os nomes das disciplinas que não tenham pré-requisitos e que não sejam pré-requisitos.

A relação é esta:

```
/* Create a table */
CREATE TABLE DISCIPLINA(CodD char(2) PRIMARY KEY, 
NomeD varchar(60), 
CargaD int, 
AreaD varchar(60), 
PreReqD char(2),
FOREIGN KEY (PreReqD) REFERENCES DISCIPLINA(CodD));


/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO DISCIPLINA VALUES('D1','TLP1',          2,  'Computação',   'D2');
INSERT INTO DISCIPLINA VALUES('D2','Cálculo 1',     4,  'Matemática',   NULL);
INSERT INTO DISCIPLINA VALUES('D3','Inglês',        2,  'Humanas',      NULL);
INSERT INTO DISCIPLINA VALUES('D4','Ed Física',     3,  'Saúde',        NULL);
INSERT INTO DISCIPLINA VALUES('D5','G Analítica',   5,  'Matemática',   'D2');
INSERT INTO DISCIPLINA VALUES('D6','Projeto Final', 6,   NULL,          'D1');
```

Eu tentei desta forma e também com LEFT JOIN, mas não obtive exito.

```
SELECT DISTINCT D1.NomeD
FROM DISCIPLINA D1, DISCIPLINA D2
WHERE D1.CodD != D2.PreReqD AND D2.PreReqD IS NULL;
```

Comment: Então só é preciso retornar o que tiver NULL, certo?

Comment: Olá Lúcio, no caso não. Pois Cálculo 1 é pré-requisito de outra matéria, então não poderia retorná-la.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voce pode fazer com LEFT JOIN mais DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.NomeD
  FROM Disciplina D
  LEFT JOIN Disciplina DPai ON DPai.PreReqD = D.CodD
 WHERE D.PreReqD IS NULL AND DPai.CodD IS NULL
```

UPDATE:

Seleciona de forma distinta apenas nomes de disciplinas

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.NomeD
```

Da tabelas de disciplinas

```
  FROM Disciplina D
```

Que possua (JOIN) ou não (LEFT) relação com outras disciplinas (PAI) que tem a disciplina principal (FILHA) como PréRequesito ( DPai.PreReqD = D.CodD )

```
  LEFT JOIN Disciplina DPai ON DPai.PreReqD = D.CodD
```

Onde a disciplina não possua pré requisitos, e não seja pré requisito de nenhuma outra disciplina

```
 WHERE D.PreReqD IS NULL AND DPai.CodD IS NULL
```

Ajudou? :)

Veja funcionando no [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba7ce/1)

Comment: Olá Thiago, funcionou perfeitamente. Você poderia dar uma explicação da lógica dessa Query? Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @WellingtonPerez, fiz um update com mais explicações.

Comment: Obrigado Thiago, cheguei até antes do where. Obrigado pela explicação!!!

Answer (score 1):

***Tente:***

```
 SELECT NomeD
FROM DISCIPLINA d
WHERE d.PreReqD IS NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM DISCIPLINA d1
     WHERE d1.PreReqD = d.CodD)
```

Veja funcionando no [SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba7ce/2)

Comment: Funciona, mas subquery no `WHERE` faz com que a subquery seja executada a cada registro de cada tabela referenciada em `FROM`. Se mesmo assim quiser, substitua `NOT IN` por `NOT EXISTS`, será mais performático.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi verdade, eu fiz até uma pergunta aqui no SO que explica isso .http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62925/not-in-ou-not-exists-qual-usar. Pergunta editada, Obrigado.

Comment: Olá Merconi, obrigado pela resposta. Funcionou aqui também!

Comment: @WellingtonPerez que bom que tenha ajudado. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
  SELECT D1.NomeD,  D2.NomeD
    FROM disciplina D1, disciplina D2
      WHERE  D2.codD = D1.PrereqD ;
```