# Select Mysql consulta portas utilizadas?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Pessoal estou precisando de fazer uma consulta da qual me retorne os valores nao utilizados, usando 3 tabelas da qual me retorne quais as portas não estao sendo utilizadas em um switch de rede

**1ª tabela**

```
sw_local id, nome
```

**2ª tabela**

```
sw_local_cliente id, id_cliente, id_sw, id_porta
```

**3ª tabela**

```
sw_porta id, porta
```

Sendo a sw_porta com valor de 1 a 16

Preciso saber quais as portas não estão sendo utilizadas nos switch's.

Comment: Já tentou algo? Mostre códigos

Comment: Jefferson, talvez ajude seu problema;https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62925/not-in-ou-not-exists-qual-usar

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz usando o IN, mas também pode ser feito usando o NOT EXISTS.

Se você quer saber quais portas determinado switch não está utilizando poderia fazer dessa forma:

```
select switch.nome,
       (
         select group_concat(porta.porta)
         from sw_porta as porta
         where porta.id not in (
                                 select switch_cliente.id_porta
                                 from sw_local_cliente as switch_cliente
                                 where switch_cliente.id_porta = porta.id and
                                       switch_cliente.id_sw = switch.id
               )
       ) as portas_nao_utilizadas
from sw_local as switch
```

Se você quer saber qual porta não está sendo utilizada em nenhum switch, poderia fazer assim:

```
select
  *
from
  sw_porta as porta
where
  porta.id not in (
    select
      switch_cliente.id_porta
    from
      sw_local_cliente as switch_cliente
  )
```

Seria isso que vc quer?