# NOT EXIST ? Como usar

Tags: sql

Pessoa, preciso de uma ajuda, preciso filtrar apenas as pessoas que possuem planos X,Y e Z que não estão na tabela outros

Por exemplo:
Tenho uma tabela de planos, onde dentro dela tem 50 planos, porém, apenas 5 tem algumas características do produto, e em outra tabela de Franquias existem todas as empresas que possuem em 5 planos. (mas existe uma falha que nem todas empresas que deveriam ter sido cadastradas na tabela Franquia estão lá)
Eu preciso filtrar as empresas que possuem o plano A,B,C,D,E que estão na tabela EMPRESAS, que não estão cadastradas na tabela Franquias

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Você poderia informar a query de até onde você conseguiu avançar.

Comment: Recomendo a leitura @Wesley: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62925/not-in-ou-not-exists-qual-usar

Comment: @WesleyGiovedi: qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados: Oracle Database? MariaDB? SQL Server? outro?

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Grosso modo seria algo como

```
select *
from   empresas
where  plano in ('A','B','C','D','E')
and    not exists (select null
                   from   Franquias
                   where  Franquias.cod_empresa = empresas.cod)
```

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso o resultado seria o seguinte:

```
SELECT E.*
  FROM EMPRESAS E
 WHERE E.PLANO IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM FRANQUIAS F
                   WHERE F.ID_EMPRESA = E.ID_EMPRESA)
```

Explicando a `query`:

- O `IN` filtrará as empresas que tenham plano A, B, C, D OU E;
- O `NOT EXISTS` verificará se existe algum registro na tabela `FRANQUIAS` utilizando o campo fictício `ID_EMPRESA` para vincular as tabelas. Caso não exista registro, a linha será retornada.

> [**Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
>
> If a subquery returns any rows at all, EXISTS subquery is TRUE, and NOT EXISTS subquery is FALSE

Ou em tradução livre:

> Se a subquery retornar qualquer linha, EXISTS será VERDADEIRO, e NOT EXISTS será FALSO

Answer (score 1):

NOT EXISTS funciona de forma contrária a EXISTS. A cláusula WHERE em NOT EXISTS será atendida se nenhuma linha for retornada pela subconsulta.

```
  SELECT Name
    FROM Production.Product
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT * 
         FROM Production.ProductSubcategory
         WHERE ProductSubcategoryID = 
                Production.Product.ProductSubcategoryID
            AND Name = 'Wheels')
```