# SELECT em uma tabela usando NOT EXISTS SQL (SERVER 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Estou tentando fazer um Select tb1 usando `Where NOT EXISTS (select* tb2)`
estou tentando selecionar a linha na tb1 que não existe na tb2 para efetuar um INSERT posteriormente.

Porém ao fazer teste no select ele não está voltando as linhas que não existem na tb2.

```
SELECT *
FROM TB1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tb2)
```

Comment: Um detalhe que esqueci de mencionar, é que a tb1 vem de linked server

Comment: Existe alguma chave para ligar as duas tabelas ?

Comment: Recomendo a leitura: [Not IN ou Not EXISTS qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62925/not-in-ou-not-exists-qual-usar)

Comment: existe o campo [Chamado] um número único, porém quando tento utilizar ele apresenta erro

Answer (score 6):

`tb1` precisa ter alguma `coluna` que referencia à `tb2`, mesmo que esta não seja uma `constraint` (a.k.a `foreign key`).

Então, digamos que `tb1` tenha a coluna `tb2_id` que referencia `tb2_id` em `tb2`, você poderá fazer assim.:

```
SELECT *
FROM TB1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT tb2_id FROM tb2 WHERE TB1.tb2_id = tb2.tb2_id)
```

Você também pode tentar.:

```
SELECT TB1.*
FROM TB1
LEFT JOIN tb2 ON TB1.tb2_id = tb2.tb2_id
WHERE tb2.tb2_id IS NULL
```

E por fim mais uma alternativa.:

```
SELECT *
FROM TB1
WHERE tb2.tb2_id NOT IN (SELECT tb2_id FROM tb2)
```

Em termos de desempenho, o `LEFT JOIN` com `IS NULL` deve ser o mais lento, a diferença entre o `NOT IN` e o `NOT EXISTS` deve ser marginal. eu ficaria com o `NOT EXISTS` por ser semanticamente mais próximo do que objetiva fazer.

E caso você não tenha um `indice` para `tb2_id` em `tb1`, lhe aconselho à criar um, pois o `NOT EXISTS` será bastante afetado pela ausência de um.

Você pode ler mais em.: [`Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?`](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

**EDIT**

Como você está utilizando um linked server, tente usar o comando OPENQUERY para consultar os dados do mesmo.

```
DECLARE @QUERY_QDE AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @QUERY_QDE = N'SELECT C.[CHAMADO], , C.[COLUNA_1], C.[COLUNA_2], ..., C.[COLUNA_N] FROM [dbo].[TB_QDE_CHAMADO] C';

SELECT CHAMADO_QDE.* 
FROM OPENQUERY([XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX], @QUERY_QDE) AS CHAMADO_QDE
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT CHAMADO_AXA.[CHAMADO] 
    FROM [_dbAXA].[dbo].[TB_QDE_CHAMADO] AS CHAMADO_AXA
    WHERE CHAMADO_QDE.[CHAMADO] = CHAMADO_AXA.[CHAMADO]
)
```

Neste caso, você terá de especificar todas as colunas na sua consulta, pois o `OPENQUERY` não entende um wildcard.

Por fim, `[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]` é o endereço do seu `LINKED SERVER`

Comment: ainda apresenta erro não sei se tem a ver mas as duas tabelas tem o mesmo nome   estou tentando, .  `SELECT*   
  FROM [ip linked].[MdbQDE].[dbo].[TB_QDE_CHAMADO] 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS  (SELECT [CHAMADO]  FROM [_dbAXA].[dbo].[TB_QDE_CHAMADO] WHERE  [ip linked].[MdbQDE].[dbo].[TB_QDE_CHAMADO].[CHAMADO] =  [_dbAXA].[dbo].[TB_QDE_CHAMADO].[CHAMADO])`  está apresentando a mensagem 
 *Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "ip link server.MdbQDE.dbo.TB_QDE_CHAMADO.CHAMADO" could not be bound.*

Comment: @DiegoPozzolini editei a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Pois é, você está tentando selecionar linhas na tb1 que não existem na tb2, mas não é isso que você escreveu. O que você escreveu foi para selecionar linhas da tb1 quando *não houver nenhuma linha na tb2* (`NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tb2)`).

O que você precisa é identificar na sua subconsulta como é que você identifica que a linha da tb2 é "igual" à linha na tb1. Por exemplo:

```
select *
  from tb1
 where not exists (
        select *
          from tb2
         where tb2.tb2_id = tb1.tb1_id
       )
```

ou algo semelhante. Agora a subconsulta trará as linhas de tb2 que são "iguais" (no caso, via comparação das colunas `tb1_id` e `tb2_id`) à linha de tb1 que o `select` principal está considerando no momento. E então ela faz o que você quer.

Answer (score 1):

Está faltando relacionar uma linha com outra linha da outra tabela.

Deveria ser algo do tipo e pressupondo que a id seja a chave de cada tabela:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
  TB1 t1
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tb2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id)
```

Dessa forma o select retornará linhas da t1 que nao existem na t2.