# Selecionando um dado em uma tabela que nao estaja contigo noutra

Tags: sql, pl-sql

Ola, eu gostaria de saber como cinteudo de um campo que nao tenha em um outra tabela. logicamente seria assim "seleciona codigo do documento em tabela x em que o codigo do documento nao exista em tabela y  ";

Comment: Deu para entender nada do que você escreveu. Tem como editar sua pergunta e escrever corretamente?

Comment: Seria algo do tipo: [Not IN ou Not EXISTS qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62925/not-in-ou-not-exists-qual-usar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que as tabelas são **x** e **y**, como mencionado, e que ambas possuem o campo **cpf**, por exemplo, a seguinte query retorna todos os CPFs existentes em **x** que não existem em **y**:

```
SELECT
    cpf
FROM
    x
WHERE
    cpf NOT IN (SELECT cpf FROM y)
```

E a seguinte, todos os CPFs que existem em **y** mas não em **x**:

```
SELECT
    cpf
FROM
    y
WHERE
    cpf NOT IN (SELECT cpf FROM x)
```

O(s) critério(s) de comparação (aqui foi usado CPF) é você que terá que definir, baseando-se em uma/algumas das colunas simultaneamente existentes nas duas tabelas.

Comment: fiquei ocupado nesses dias mas obrigado pela dica, funcionou