# Como buscar dados de uma tabela usando referencia de outras?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query

Vou exemplificar com uma coisa simples...

Tenho uma tabela 'produtos' que tem nas colunas, id,nomedoproduto,valor.
tenho outra tabela 'users' colunas, id, nome.
E outra tabela 'comprasdosusuarios' id, id_user, id_produtos, nomedoproduto,
esse terceira tabela é gerada apartir dessas duas primeiras... até ai OK.

Quero buscar na tabela 'produtos' todos itens menos os itens que tem 'id_user'(da tabela compras)= 1 por ex

```
produtos
id          nomedoproduto, valor
1           Roupa           100 
2           Telefone         500
3           Geladeira        1500
4           TV              1000
5           Microondas      300
6           Sofá            600

users
id nome
1 José
2 Felipe

Compras dos usuários
id   id_user id_produtos produtos
1       1         1       Roupa
2       1         2       Telefone
3       1         3       Geladeira
4       2         1        Roupa
```

Bom... se o usuário já comprou... eu quero que não apareça na lista mais.
como uso isso com select?

Comment: Você quer todos os produtos que ainda não foram comprados por ninguém. Isso?

Comment: @DanEven utilize join https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp para fazer um select a duas tabelas, ou mais..

Comment: Recomendo a leitura: [Not IN ou Not EXISTS qual usar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62925/not-in-ou-not-exists-qual-usar)?

Comment: Não, na verdade por usuario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a cláusula `EXISTS` em conjunto com `NOT`:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM produtos p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM comprasdosusuarios cdu
                   WHERE cdu.id_produtos = p.id
                     AND cdu.id_user = 1)
   AND p.nomedoproduto LIKE '%roupa%'
```

> [**Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
>
> If a subquery returns any rows at all, EXISTS subquery is TRUE, and NOT EXISTS subquery is FALSE

Ou em tradução livre:

> Se a subquery retornar qualquer linha, EXISTS será VERDADEIRO, e NOT EXISTS será FALSO

Comment: Obrigado!   Funcionou!

Comment: Só mais uma duvida! para mim é meio complexo esse código... entao , como juntaria com um "filtros".... produtos = 'roupa' or produtos = 'TV' ??

Comment: @DanEven coloquei um `WHERE` a mais para exemplificar o filtro