# Select com join não retorna resultados

Tags: sql

Tenho as seguintes tabelas

---

```
livro
id int pk

passador
id int pk
fk_livro_id int
ordem int
```

Estou fazendo uma tela de listagem de livros. O objetivo é trazer todos os livros que não estão registrados no passador

---

Fiz  a seguinte query:

`SELECT * FROM livro as l JOIN passador as p ON l.id != p.fk_livro_id AND like %?%`

Quando tenho ao menos um livro cadastrado no passador a pesquisa funciona normalmente, contudo quando não há livro no passador a pesquisa retorna sempre vazia.

Comment: Recomendo a leitura: [Not IN ou Not EXISTS qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62925/not-in-ou-not-exists-qual-usar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adaptei uma consulta:

```
select * from livro as l 
where l.id not in (select fk_livro_id from passador)
```

É feito um subselect que trás todos os `fk_livros_id` sendo assim, comparo com os `id` da tabela de livros e exibo apenas os que não tem na tabela `passador`

Comment: O resultado é o mesmo, quando não há pelo menos um livro cadastrado no passador a busca não retorna resultados, contudo se houver 1 funciona perfeitamente

Comment: @AdrianoLuz confere novamente, eu editei o select.

Comment: Exatamente isso que estava procurando. Só gostaria de aplicar a mesma lógica utilizando join

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa de solução utilizando `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM livro 
LEFT JOIN passador
   ON livro.id = passador.fk_livro_id
WHERE passador.fk_livro_id IS NULL
```