# Update ou insert com dados de outra tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Tenho esse comando `SQL` para atualizar a tabela`REQUISICOES` com os dados da tabela`REQUISICOES_ATUALIZA`.

Uso como chave para atualizar o campo numero_requisicao, mas preciso que caso não encontre `correspondencia` na tabela `REQUISICOES`, insira um novo registro vindo da tabela `REQUISICOES_ATUALIZA`;

Esse funciona para atualizar:

```
UPDATE requisicoes a
JOIN requisicoes_atualiza b
SET a.projeto = b.projeto
WHERE a.numero_requisicao = b.numero_requisicao
```

E como seria o SQL para os que não existem?

Comment: Qual seria o novo registro caso não exista?

Comment: Se você entender sobre, vai conseguir resolver seu problema: [Not IN ou Not EXISTS qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62925/not-in-ou-not-exists-qual-usar)

Comment: Caso não exista um numero de requisição correspondente na tabela Requisicoes, quero inserir os dados da tabela requisicoes_atualiza... Marconi

Comment: Estou usando MYSQL!

Answer (score 1):

Usando o `NOT EXISTS`. Se o campo `numero_requisição` for uma unique declarada, você pode usar o [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO requisicoes (numero_requisicao, projeto)
SELECT numero_requisicao, projeto
FROM requisicoes_atualiza ra
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE projeto = ra.projeto
```

Comment: Onde vc faz o update nesse sql??

Comment: @AndreMaia. Não estou fazendo `update`. Estou fazendo somente a inserção dos itens que ainda não existem, que é o que está na pergunta, correto? Teoricamente o 'update' foi feito com a outra instrução de `update` que já consta na pergunta.

Comment: Quero fazer no mesmo comando, seria possível?

Comment: @AndreMaia, Editei a resposta. Veja se lhe atende

Comment: não atende porque o campo não é chave, e se eu colocar tenho outras chaves na tabela.

Comment: Não precisa ser `primary key`, precisa ser `unique`. Se não for desse jeito, então não dá para fazer `insert...update`, faça as duas instruções separadas.

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer o insert do que não está na sua tabela de requisições pode usar o SQL abaixo

```
INSERT INTO requisicoes (numero_requisicao, projeto)
SELECT b.numero_requisicao, b.projeto
FROM requisicoes a
LEFT JOIN requisicoes_atualiza b on a.numero_requisicao = b.numero_requisicao
WHERE a.numero_requisicao is null
```

Eu uso bastante essa tabela quando tenho esse tipo de duvida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]