# Listar Dias faltantes do período no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como seria possível fazer com o que no SQL Server ao confrontar uma tabela que guarda os registros de status de um determinado código com uma tabela virtual do período (Calendário de dias) ele me traga todos os códigos que estão faltando nesses determinados dias

Por Exemplo minha tabela guarda apenas os registros validos

```
DATA - COD - STATUS
01/07/2018 - 123456 - Ok
01/07/2018 - 987654 - Ok
02/07/2018 - 123456 - Ok
03/07/2018 - 123456 - Ok
04/07/2018 - 987654 - OK
05/07/2018 - 987654 - OK
06/07/2018 - 123456 - Ok
08/07/2018 - 987654 - OK
09/07/2018 - 123456 - Ok
09/07/2018 - 987654 - Ok
10/07/2018 - 123456 - Ok
```

Seria possível obter o seguinte resultado por Select onde me traga os dias que estão faltando por exemplo?

```
DATA - COD - STATUS
01/07/2018 - 123456 - Ok
01/07/2018 - 987654 - Ok
02/07/2018 - 123456 - Ok
02/07/2018 - 987654 - Fail
03/07/2018 - 123456 - Ok
03/07/2018 - 987654 - Fail
04/07/2018 - 123456 - Fail
04/07/2018 - 987654 - OK
05/07/2018 - 123456 - Fail
05/07/2018 - 987654 - OK
06/07/2018 - 123456 - Ok
06/07/2018 - 987654 - Fail
07/07/2018 - 123456 - Fail
07/07/2018 - 987654 - Fail
08/07/2018 - 123456 - Fail
08/07/2018 - 987654 - OK
09/07/2018 - 123456 - Ok
09/07/2018 - 987654 - Ok
10/07/2018 - 123456 - Ok
10/07/2018 - 987654 - Fail
```

**Complemento - 30/07/2018**

```
SELECT B.COD, B.DATA, B.[E] ENTRADA, B.[S] SAIDA
  FROM (SELECT P.COD, P.DATA, P.TPMARCA, P.HORA
          FROM PREG P
         WHERE P.DATA BETWEEN '20180701' AND '20180715'
           AND P.COD = '003100'
           AND P.TPMC <> 'D'
           AND P.REP <> ' '
       ) A
 PIVOT (SUM(A.HORA)
   FOR A.TPMARCA IN ([E], [S])) AS B
```

Esse é o meu SELECT e esse é o resultado dele

```
COD DATA    ENTRADA SAIDA
003100  20180701    6,53    19,13
003100  20180702    7,18    18,03
003100  20180706    6,54    19,06
003100  20180707    6,34    13,08
003100  20180708    7,18    NULL
003100  20180709    NULL    18,9
003100  20180712    6,48    18,43
003100  20180714    7,02    18,11
```

Porém o resultado que eu preciso é

```
COD DATA    ENTRADA SAIDA
003100  20180701    6,53    19,13
003100  20180702    7,18    18,03
003100  20180705    NULL    NULL
003100  20180706    6,54    19,06
003100  20180707    6,34    13,08
003100  20180708    7,18    NULL
003100  20180709    NULL    18,9
003100  20180710    NULL    NULL
003100  20180711    NULL    NULL
003100  20180712    6,48    18,43
003100  20180713    NULL    NULL
003100  20180714    7,02    18,11
003100  20180715    NULL    NULL
```

Ou seja, preciso que traga também os dias que não existem registros

Comment: Seria isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62925/not-in-ou-not-exists-qual-usar

Answer (score 2):

Seu exemplo não está claro. Devemos considerar somente os CODs do período listado?

Independente da resposta para a questão acima:

Sim, é possível gerar uma lista contínua de datas virtualmente (sem precisar nem mesmo criar uma tabela temporria) assim:

```
Select data from(
SELECT TOP (365) DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number), '2018/01/01') as data FROM [master]..spt_values) datas
where data between '2018-07-01' and '2018-07-31'
```

veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/26723).

O problema é saber quais CODs que você quer.

Eu criei um exemplo extamente com a sua amostra de dados e chamei a tabela de ATIVIDADE.

Podemos supor que toda a amostra de COD esta no seu exemplo, então a query abaixo é válida:

```
select aux2.data, aux1.cod from
(select distinct cod from atividade) aux1
cross join
(Select data from(
SELECT TOP (365) DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number), '2018/01/01') as data FROM [master]..spt_values) datas
where data between '2018-07-01' and '2018-07-31') aux2
```

veja no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76784/1)

Isso cria um resultado com todas as datas e CODs possíveis.

Agora é só cruzar as informações usando o `left join`

```
select distinct aux3.data, aux3.cod, coalesce(atividade.status,'fail') as status
FROM
(select aux2.data, aux1.cod from
  (select distinct cod from atividade) aux1
   cross join
  (Select data from(
       SELECT TOP (365) DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number), '2018/01/01') as data FROM [master]..spt_values) datas
   where data between '2018-07-01' and '2018-07-31') aux2) aux3
left join atividade on atividade.data=aux3.data and atividade.cod=aux3.cod
 order by aux3.data, aux3.cod
```

Mais uma vez, aqui esta o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76784/4)

## Nota:

Caso existam CODs que deveriam aparecer, mas não estão no seu exemplo,  basta subsitituir

```
select distinct cod from atividade
```

por

```
select cod from CODs  -- lista de CODs válidos para o período.
```

Comment: Eu entendi o que você colocou, irei deixar um exemplo mais concreto do que realmente estou precisando

Comment: Será sempre um unico COD, ex.  `P.COD = '003100'`, e sempre um intervalo de datas fixo?

Comment: pode conter vários códigos e vai sem sempre em um intervalo, por exemplo, os últimos 15 dias ou 7 dias

Comment: Nós precisamos que você nos forneça um exemplo daquilo que voce quer fazer. A idéia sera sempre a mesma, fazer um join com um conjunto sequencial de datas. O que vai mudar é a determinação do conjunto de CODs. Se forem vários CODs a query será diferente de um unico COD.

Comment: O Exemplo está bem definido, coloquei apenas um código para não ficar muito extenso, preciso apenas que o SELECT também preencha os dias que não existam nessa tabela, trazendo de alguma forma esses registros inexistentes.

Comment: Deste jeito fica complicado. A cada instante sua necessidade muda. Aqui está um fiddle mais ou menos génerico para o núcleo da sua query. Ela vai trazer todos os CODs e datas da tabela PREG mais as datas faltantes para cada COD. Não tenho como fornecer sua query completa porque nao tenho suas tabelas. Caso queira algo completo, forneça um fiddle com um exemplo minimo realizavel do que você quer fazer. Verifique se é isto: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a4505/5

Comment: A necessidade não mudou, eu que mudei os exemplos para tentar facilitar um entendimento, pois a necessidade é que o SELECT também traga os dias que não existem.

Comment: Analise o ultimo fiddle. Verifique se é bem isso o que você quer. Caso contrário, forneça um fiddle com um modelo de dados testável.