# Exibir registro quando outra tabela não existir referência

Tags: sql

Preciso que apenas exiba algum registro se o campo `id` da tabela `noticias`  não tiver referência no campo `idnoticia` da tabela `fotos_noticias`.

```
SELECT
    noticias.id,
    noticias.titulo,
    noticias.slug,
    fotos_noticias.foto
FROM noticias
INNER JOIN fotos_noticias
    ON noticias.id <> fotos_noticias.idnoticia
WHERE
GROUP BY noticias.id
```

Infelizmente este SQL acima exibe todos os registros sem restrição

Comment: Recomendo leitura: [Not IN ou Not EXISTS qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62925/not-in-ou-not-exists-qual-usar)

Comment: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados: Oracle Database? MariaDB? PostgreSQL? SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analisando a seguinte imagem:

[image: SQL Joins Cheatsheet]

Você quer fazer um `LEFT JOIN` (o gráfico a esquerda, o de baixo) eliminando os resultados onde as tabelas se interseccionam. Para isso basta usar `WHERE tabela_b.id IS NULL`.

No seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
    noticias.id,
    noticias.titulo,
    noticias.slug,
    fotos_noticias.foto
FROM noticias
LEFT JOIN fotos_noticias
    ON noticias.id = fotos_noticias.idnoticia
WHERE fotos_noticias.idnoticia IS NULL
GROUP BY noticias.id
```

Answer (score 4):

Gladison, Vejamos se eu entendi:

Você quer todos os registros da tabela noticias que não existam em fotos_noticias? Se sim o select seria esse:

```
SELECT noticias.id, noticias.titulo, noticias.slug, fotos_noticias.foto
  FROM noticias   
 WHERE noticias.id not in ( select idnoticia from fotos_noticias)
 GROUP BY noticias.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Na Teoria dos conjuntos o que você procura é C = A - B onde A são as notícias e B são as fotos.

Há várias formas de solucionar o que necessita. Segue algumas usando T-SQL.

```
-- código #1
SELECT id from noticias
except
SELECT idnoticia from fotos_noticias;
```

ou

```
-- código #2
SELECT N.id 
  from noticias as N
       left join fotos_noticias as FN on FN.idnoticia = N.id
  where FN.idnoticia is null;
```

ou

```
-- código #3
SELECT N.id
  from noticias as N
  where not exists (SELECT * 
                      from fotos_noticias as FN
                      where FN.idnoticia = N.id);
```

ou

```
-- código #4
SELECT N.id
  from noticias as N
  where not in (SELECT FN.idnoticia
                      from fotos_noticias as FN);
```

Não testei; pode(m) existir erro(s).