# Como usar GROUP_CONCAT na cláusula WHERE, com números?

Tags: mysql

Bom dia.

Tenho as seguintes tabelas numa base MySQL:

```
BOIS
------------
| id | boi |
------------
| 12 | 77  |
| 22 |  8  |
| 14 | 12  |
------------

BOIS_MANEJO
---------------------
| id | fk_boi| peso |
---------------------
|  1 |   14  |  217 |
---------------------
|  2 |   22  |  217 |
---------------------
|  3 |   14  |  250 |
---------------------
```

A seguinte Query me trás todos os ids dos bois.

```
    SELECT *
FROM bois
WHERE 
    id NOT IN(
    SELECT CONCAT("'", GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(m.fk_boi) SEPARATOR "','"), "'") FROM bois_manejo AS m
    )
```

Eu obtenho o ID 12 somente com as seguintes fórmulas.

```
    SELECT id 
FROM bois
WHERE 
    id NOT IN(14, 22)
# OU id NOT IN('14', '22')
```

Como posso usar o GROUP_CONCAT com números, ou como posso resolver essa situação?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Qual é o resultado esperado?

Comment: @FilipeL.Constante, o resultado esperado é o ID 12. É o único que não está na tabela bois_manejo.

Comment: Não entendi o motivo de você tentar uma outra forma, uma vez que já tem o select que lhe traz o resultado esperado..

Comment: @FilipeL.Constante, eu não tenho o SELECT que trás o 12. Se está falando do SELECT que deu certo (o segundo) ele dá certo só porque eu sei os códigos que estão lá. O objetivo da query é me trazer os resultados conforme há mudança na base/alimentação da tabela. O primeiro select me trás todos os IDs.

Comment: @E.Coelho qual a entrada e saída que você espera?

Comment: Então, pelo que eu entendi, você precisa fazer um select que traga um resultado com base em uma alteração de uma outra tabela, no caso (bois_manejo), é isso? Consegue ser um pouco mais claro na sua dúvida? :)

Comment: @Sorack, como pode ver, estou tentando fazer com que a cláusula WHERE pegue todas as Foreng Keys que existem na tabela bois_manejo (com um DISTINCT) e me entregue todos os IDs que não constam em bois_manejo. No exemplo o único ID que não está na tabela bois_manejo é o 12.

Comment: @FilipeL.Constante fk_boi é uma Foreng Key relacionada ao ID da tabela boi. Eu preciso trazer só os IDs dos bois que não foram pesados/manejados ainda. :)

Comment: Tudo bem, eu entendi a estrutura da tabelam eu não entendi como eu sei que  eles foram ou não foram pesados/manejados ainda! hehe :)

Comment: @E.Coelho você tem a necessidade de utilizar obrigatoriamente o group_concat?? existe alguma problema em usar outras alternativas??

Comment: Bom dia, @Oliveira. Estou aberto a alternativas. Até o momento estou preso nessa. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A subquery retorna os registros que possuem relacionamento entre a tabela bois e bois_manejo pelo id e fk_bois respectivamente pelo INNER JOIN. Nesse cenário os registros que estão em bois mas não estão em bois_manejo não estarão no resultado da query e poderá comparar com o NOT IN, dessa forma o id 12 será apresentado.*

```
SELECT * FROM bois WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT bois.id FROM bois INNER JOIN bois_manejo ON bois.id = bois_manejo.fk_boi)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, @Oliveira. Eu não sabia que isso era possível. A cláusula IN lê os valores de uma espécie de array retornado, ou lê somente os números? Eu posso usar essa opção quando estiver lidando só com números? Outra coisa: esse modelo é mais eficiente em relação ao processamento?

Comment: @E.Coelho, nesse caso é comparado apenas pela coluna id da tabela bois, o IN permite verificar se o valor de uma coluna está presente em uma lista de elementos, mas vc pode comparar com outras colunas, no caso a alternativa o operador Exists https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62925/not-in-ou-not-exists-qual-usar/63279

Comment: Show de bola, @Oliveira! Muito obrigado por compartilhar teu conhecimento e nos ajudar. Tudo de bom! (Ah... toma cuidado com o Obiwan - dissestes que és apenas um padawan - porque o cara mente pacas! hehehe)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer de maneira mais simples, e mais eficiente, utilizando a cláusula NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT * FROM bois
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM bois_manejo WHERE bois_manejo.fk_boi = bois.id);
```