# Delete - Qual o mais rápido?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso deletar de um tabela grande alguns registros.
Qual a melhor alternativa:
Usar

```
DELETE Tabela where id in (select id from @temporaria)
```

ou

```
delete Tabela WHERE exists (select id from @temporaria  where estoque.id = id)
```

usar `IN` ou `EXISTS` ???
Ou existe alguma alternativa melhor ?

Comment: isso vai depender do banco de dados, de como o motor otimiza  a query, como não disse qual o banco, seria só especulação responder, mas a melhor maneira de saber, para a query em específico, seria executar algum analisador de query para ver a melhor opção

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Not IN ou Not EXISTS qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62925/not-in-ou-not-exists-qual-usar)

Comment: Sua tabela tem um volume de dados bastante grande? Se não tiver não gaste seu tempo se preocupando com isso. Analise, isto sim, os possíveis efeitos colaterais de IN/NOT IN na eventual ocorrência de NULL.

Comment: É evental ? Rode o delete correto e se preocupe com outras coisas. Sendo necessário rodar sempre um cursor talvez seja a melhor solução.

Comment: A tabela é grande  com mais de 56 milhões de registros, estou apagando algo em torno de 1500 registros. Pelo que que falaram quando utilizo IN ele onera o banco.  Não notei diferença em usar IN ou EXISTS. Estou Usando SQL Server Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)

Comment: **(1)** Na tabela `@temporaria` a coluna `id` é chave primária ou exclusiva (*unique*)?   **(2)** Em `Tabela`, a coluna `id` é a chave primária?

Answer (score 2):

Ótima pergunta.

O artigo **[Apagar conjunto de linhas em tabelas enormes](https://portosql.wordpress.com/blog/)** trata justamente em como apagar conjunto de linhas em tabelas enormes evitando (ou tentando...) parar os outros processos que estão em execução simultânea e acessando a mesma tabela.

Com relação às duas abordagens apresentadas pelo autor do tópico, IN ou EXISTS, a solução é sempre analisar o [plano de execução](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/11/21/o-plano-perfeito/) para avaliar qual pode ser mais eficiente. Sugiro a leitura do artigo “[Qual é mais rápido: NOT IN ou NOT EXISTS?](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2020/05/02/not-in-x-not-exists/)”.

Curiosamente, às vezes se percebe que o *query optimizer* gera o mesmo plano de execução para consultas com abordagens diferentes, pois tudo depende dos predicados existentes no código da consulta, dos índices disponíveis e alguns outros fatores. Por exemplo, no caso em questão se a coluna `id` nas duas tabelas for chave primária (ou possuir o atributo *unique*) pode permitir um plano de execução mais eficiente. Outro cuidado é garantir que as estatísticas estejam atualizadas.

É preciso ficar atento ao *lock escalation*, mas como são apagadas cerca de 1.500 linhas por execução, então não se corre o risco da tabela ficar bloqueada. Detalhes em [Guia de Controle de Versão de Linha e Bloqueio de Transações](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide).

Comment: Ótimo artigo esse Apagar conjunto de linhas em tabelas enormes, não conhecia e já favoritei. Obrigado!

Comment: @VictorFreidinger Eu que agradeço pelo retorno sobre o artigo; ele foi publicado há poucos dias. A pergunta do Celso é ótima, por trazer à discussão o tema.